# Get Request.Form values in Webmethod

Tags: asp.net

i use webmethod , and in that

i use want value from input text box , using Request.form ,

how to get  form input values in WebMethod using Ajax post

my problem is  ,  i pass some inputs as parameters to webmethod, but want other to be retrieved from using Request.Form , but i get as blank in variable

**i have used runat="server" for input type="text"**

i have tried

```
string setrname = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["selectroomname"];
```

but this give as null

pls advice
maulik

Comment: in `ASP.NET`, `WebMethod`s are static functions, you cannot have a non-static field usage inside a static method, you won't get anything, your best chances are to pass the textbox value through that very ajax request

Comment: but i add new html (append from jquery) and can have array of values ..  i use web service , so that i show loading/searching image, and in background , fill datatable getting all request.form values and then redirect

Answer (score 1):

Work on below code and let me know what you get output:

```
int v = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Keys.Count;
        string var = "";
        string[] name1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys;
        if(name1 != null)
        {
        foreach (string name in name1)
        {
            if (name != null)
            {
                var = var + "[" + name.Trim() + "]-" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[name].ToString().Trim();
                var = var + "---";
               //store it and compare according to your value--selectroomname 
            }
        }
```

Comment: in this  :  string[] name1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys;   i get as null

Comment: i use textarea in html... and append new textarea from jquery...so  for exp.. i have a textarea , and i append new textarea ... the value for second textarea is saved in database, and value for first is blank...
   first textarea in source code is like ...  <textarea id="GetTextArea1" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" name="GetActivityText[1]" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your `WebMethod` is something like below

```
[WebMethod]
public static string MyWebMethod(..
```

You cannot access `Page` Controls i.e. `TextBox` and others inside a static method, because they are non-static.

you should instead pass the TextBox's value from the client side itself in your ajax i.e.

```
   var url='/Default.aspx/MyWebMethod';
   var value = document.getElementById('textBoxId').value;
   var data={myField:value};
   makeAjaxRequest(url,data,callback);
   function callback(data){
      ///this is where you recieve ajax success
   }
```

where `makeAjaxRequest` is a simple wrap over your ajax sending function, something like

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function makeAjaxRequest(url,data,callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: data,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: callback
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: i use ajax.post and return url and then window.location.href is called

Comment: @user2838660, tell me this, are you using a separate `WebService` i.e. `.asmx` file?

Comment: no....in ajax post : i use hotels.aspx/BindValues  ,where the BindValues WebMethod is in hotels.aspx.cs

Comment: great, then remember this,`Request.Form["key"]` won't give you any thing, you should try to pass your textbox values through ajax itself, see my updated answer

Comment: ok.i will then pass parameters. if i want to get value of all input with same name like  <input type="text" name="asudus[]" value="22">,<input type="text" name="asudus[]" value="44">,<input type="text" name="asudus[]" value="12">...i want the three above values in jquery using name attribute,,how to do this